# How to remove elements from GXT HtmlLayoutContainer

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have the following Widget that uses GXT HtmlLayoutContainer:

```
public class MyWidget implements IsWidget {

    public interface MyWidgetLayout extends XTemplates {
        @XTemplate(source = "my/stuff/resources/MyWidget.html")
        SafeHtml getTemplate(List<MyData> myData);
    }

    public static final MyWidgetLayout LAYOUT = GWT.create(MyWidgetLayout .class);

    private final List<MyData> myData;

    private HtmlLayoutContainer container;

    public TaskRegulationsContainer(List<MyData> myData) {
        this.myData = myData;
    }

    @Override
    public Widget asWidget() {
        if (container == null) {
            container = new HtmlLayoutContainer(LAYOUT.getTemplate(regulations, postfix));

            if (null != regulations) {
                for (MyData d : myData) {
                    MyOtherWidget w = new MyOtherWidget(d);
                    container.add(w, new AbstractHtmlLayoutContainer.HtmlData(".my-data-" + myData.getUniqueId()));
                }
            }
        }

        return container;
    }

    public void handleRemovedData(MyData removedData) {
        // How can I remove the widget corresponding to removedData
        // with the selector my-data-{uniqueId}?
    }
}
```

with the following template:

```
<style>
</style>

<div>
    <span>My Data:</span>
    <div>
        <tpl for="myData">
            <div class="my-data-{uniqueId}"></div>
        </tpl>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I remove individual `myData` list items from the UI after the template is rendered?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the children of the container, check if the class attribute contains "my-data-" + uniqueId and delete it.
Something like this should work:

```
public void handleRemovedData(MyData removedData) {
  for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
    node = pParent.getChild(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      Element element = (Element) node.cast();
      if (element.getClassName().contains("my-data-" + removedData.getUniqueId())) {
        container.removeChild(element);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had tried container.select("my-data-" + removedData.getUniqueId()), removeChildren() and then removeFromParent(), but it was not removing all children leaving inner divs behind.  I believe there is a bug in GXT's XTemplates.  I have switched to use a FlowContainer instead.

Comment: can you past the generated HTML in your question? The removeChild method should work as it is a GWT method.

Comment: I have tried them all, including recursively going through the child DOM nodes one by one and removing them.  The issue is that when you use GXT's <tpl for=...> tags to display a list of widgets, the widgets are displayed, but are not truly attached to their parent.  Very odd, but I can't find another way of explaining it.  Unfortunately, I don't have any more time to spend on it either; I have already wasted ~6-7 hours on this issue :(

Comment: This sounds strange. You should ask this question in the Sencha/GXT Gitter room. Is this is an issue, Sencha should know this.